# C++ Equivalent of Pages.Add() in Visual Studio Windows Forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, forms, c++-cli

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and trying to make a Multi-Page Windows Forms.

I need a C++/CLI equivalent of this C# code:

```
public CreateUserWizard(CreateUserContext context)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Pages.Add(new WelcomePage());
    Pages.Add(new UserNamePage(context));
    Pages.Add(new PasswordPage(context));
    Pages.Add(new AdvancedPasswordOptionsPage(context));
    Pages.Add(new SummaryPage(context));
    Pages.Add(new ProgressPage(context));
    Pages.Add(new CompletePage(context));
}
```

This C# code was downloaded from this source: http://winformswizard.codeplex.com/. I just need to know how to write for example this code into C++/CLI:

```
Pages.Add(new WelcomePage());
```

Comment: If you're using WinForms, you don't want a translation to C++, you want a translation to C++/CLI. If you actually do want a C++ application, then you can't use WinForms.

Comment: Yes i need a C++/CLI translation. I am just trying to make a Multi-Page Windows Forms and don't know how to do it having a C# code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that in managed C++, you simply use the [pointer-to-member operator (`->`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8336763%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and must use [`gcnew`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/te3ecsc8%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) in place of `new`, like so:

```
Pages->Add(gcnew WelcomePage());
```

Comment: Yes it is true but I have already tried this and got the error: "error C2065: 'Pages' : undeclared identifier"